# UITableView Cell ImageView issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

Hi
I have a `UITableView` in my class and when i tried to load the contents am getting a screen like this

[image]

Below the white box am not able to see the horizodal separator line , Please help me.

My code:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [names count];    //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"service";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]
        ;
    }

    // Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    // Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image
    cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(5,10,50,60);
    cell.imageView.image=[imaages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return 80;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write in your view did load

In iOS 7 and later, cell separators do not extend all the way to the edge of the table view.This property sets the default inset for all cells in the table, much like rowHeight sets the default height for cells. It is also used for managing the “extra” separators drawn at the bottom of plain style tables.

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
if ([_tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [_tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Comment: no...still its not working

Comment: _tabview is your table view object , may be in your case self.tableView. try it

Comment: [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
  this is working

Comment: yes its the same , but it will crash in case if you run this in ios 6.0, because setSeparatorInset method is available after 7.0, that why i have checked first if table view respond to setSeparatorInset.